# Using Windows Command to search multiple folders for a file and to copy it to another location

Tags: find, copy

I have multiple files in a folder:

```
P:\Management_System
```

There are multiple sub folders inside my folder `Management_System`.

I am trying to see if it's possible to search for a file by it's name e.g `"Safety Manual for Climbing"` inside `Management_System`  and if it exists, I want to copy it to another location. 
I am not a programmer. I have used copy to copy files, but I do not know how to make the search look into all sub folders for the file.
Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In command line, try:

```
for /f tokens^=* %i in ('%__APPDIR__%where.exe /r P:\Management_System "Safety Manual for Climbing.*"')do copy "%~i" "c:\some\folder\for\sample"
```

If the file extension known, add it:

```
for /f tokens^=* %i in ('%__APPDIR__%where.exe /r P:\Management_System "Safety Manual for Climbing.pdf"')do copy "%~i" "c:\some\folder\for\sample"
```

If you want to test the output first without copy any file, add `echo\` before your `copy` command:

```
for /f tokens^=* %i in ('%__APPDIR__%where.exe /r P:\Management_System "Safety Manual for Climbing.pdf"')do echo\copy "%~i" "c:\some\folder\for\sample"
```

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[For](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**

  [√] **[For /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

  [√] **[Echo](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html)**

  [√] **[Copy](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html)**

  [√] **[Where](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html)**